# logistic regression doesn't converge consistently MVC C# accord

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logistic-regression, accord.net

I'm working on a project to calculate probability using logistic regression. So, here is my code.

We don't have enough false data to support the analysis, so we create a way to spoof false inputs. Normally we have 10 positive inputs, then we spoof 10 false inputs. After that we try to compute this. If the result doesn't converge, we abandon the last set of false inputs and create another set, until the result converge. After the result has converged, we save the false inputs we produce. However, the problem is that if we try to compute it again with the saved false inputs with the original positive inputs, the result doesn't converge like it did the first time. To my knowledge, if I use the same set of data, the result should be the same from logistic regression analysis, but it doesn't seem true for this project. Any suggestion?

Here is my code. I'm using Accord.Statistics.Analysis:

```
regression = new LogisticRegressionAnalysis(allInput, allOutput);
                isConverged = regression.Compute(1e-005, 50);
                if (isConverged)
                {
                    //Save the fake data to the db when it converges.
                    UserTimeServices uts = new UserTimeServices();
                    uts.populateTimeProfile(trueFakeInput, true, user.UserGuid);
                    uts.populateTimeProfile(falseFakeInput, false, user.UserGuid);

                    return Math.Round(regression.Regression.Compute(loginTimes.ToArray()), 5);
                }
            }
        }// the part above is in a while loop. 
        var regressionAnalysis = new LogisticRegressionAnalysis(input, output);
        bool converging = regressionAnalysis.Compute(1e-005, 50);// it always doesnt converge even with the same set of data.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is the first parameter of RegressionAnalysis.Compute?

Comment: the code is done in asp.net-mvc framework.

Comment: @RichardSzalay First parameter(1e-005) is the difference between two iterations of the regression algorithm when the algorithm should stop. Second one (50) is the maximum number of iterations. I tried to take them off but the result is still the same.

Comment: @TitanTheYaphet What I meant was, is the first parameter of `Compute` an `int`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, etc?